# Small Wire gauges

Tags: wire, small-gauge-wire

I would like to determine the wire gauge of small, Cu, multi-strand wire. Between 18 and 32 AWG. I can count the # of strands and measure the diameter of the wire strands with a micrometer. But what I can't do is figure out the AWG. Is there an app that takes as input # strands and strand diameter and spits out the AWG?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about an app, but it's pretty easy to google for a wire construction chart such as [this](http://www.philatron.com/words-pdf-image-files/wire-strand-construction-chart.pdf) one.

[image]

Alternately, measure the diameter of one of the strands (assuming they are all equal), calculate the cross-sectional area per strand, multiply by the number of strands and calculate the AWG from the total cross-sectional area, as so:

AWG = \$ 36 - 4.3124(\ln(n\cdot\frac{\pi}{4}\cdot d_s^2) + 4.3686) \$

n = number of strands

ds = diameter of one strand in mm

Comparing with the chart, 7/38 (ds = 0.101mm) would be 29.6 gauge, which agrees well with the AWG 30 in the chart.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily figure it out yourself;

Find the cross-sectional area of a single strand, multiply that area times the number of strands in the wire, and correlate that total area with the AWG for that area via a copper wire table.